# Google Sheets Formula: Comparing lists of data in two columns

Tags: google-sheets-formula, array-formulas

| Incoming | Outgoing | Same Day |
| --- | --- | --- |
|  | 12/5/2022 |  |
| 8/1/2022, 8/10/2022, 8/11/2022, 8/15/2022, 8/16/2022, 8/8/2022 |  |  |
| 8/11/2022 | 8/11/2022 | ***True*** |
|  |  |  |
| 7/12/2022, 7/9/2022, 10/3/2022, 11/17/2022 | 10/3/2022, 11/17/2022, 12/25/2022 | ***True*** |
|  | 8/10/2022 |  |
| 1/5/2023, 2/29/2023 | 1/5/2023 | ***True*** |
| 3/14/2023, 3/15/2023 | 1/5/2023, 1/6/2023 |  |

I have a table with two columns, which each contain between zero and many dates delimited by a ", ".  I'm trying to develop a formula in a third column that sets a flag if there is one or more match in the prior two columns.

For example, the third, fifth, and seventh rows have the same date in both columns and are thus flagged "True" under the [Same Day] column.

I'm trying something like:

```
IF(ARRAYFORMULA(SPLIT(", ",... ...),True,)
```

I think a nested arrayformulas, splits, and/or queries would be appropriate, but it's tricky.

Are there formulas that one can use as operators on sets; like:

```
SPLIT(", ",[Incoming]) - SPLIT(", ",[Outgoing]) = "Unique Items from [Incoming]" ?
```

, Any thoughts ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

*You may try:*

```js
=map(A2:A,B2:B,lambda(a,b,if(sum(index(iferror(xmatch(split(a,","),split(b,",")))))>0,true,)))
```

[image]